# All exported functions from a Win32 DLL have same entry point

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I am facing an issue with a Windows DLL file. I am creating a DLL project using Visual studio 2017. I simply exported 3 functions (function1, function2 and function3) from the dll. When I view my dll in dependency walker it shows all the three exported functions from the dll but all the three exported functions have the same entry point i.e 0x00001000.

Whether I call function1 or function2 or function3 from my another application that is using the above dll it always calls the function1.

Please let me know how to create dll that maps functions with 1:1 entry point.

There are only two files (.h and .cpp) in my dll project. The functions are defined in a header file like

```
extern "C"
{
_declspec(dllexport) void function1();
_declspec(dllexport) void function2();
_declspec(dllexport) void function3();
}
```

In the source file I am defining functions as

```
void function1()
{
    int f1 = 0;
}

void function2()
{
    int f2 = 0;
}

void function3()
{
    int f3 = 0;
}
```

From my another application I use LoadLibraryEx() and GetProcAddress() to return the function address. GetProceAddress always returns the same function pointer.

Here is the view of Dependency walker of my dll

[image: dependency walker]

Comment: how are the functions defined? post some code...

Comment: Please post a [mcve] And are you using a .def file?

Comment: I updated the post with code example

Comment: Use Dependency Walker to inspect the module exports.

Comment: Hey come on! I told all the three function are properly exported from the dll but have the same entry point that is main issue with my dll.

Comment: It's comdat folding -the code in each function is the same - so only one copy of the function is retained in the final DLL.

Comment: Thanks Richard !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Msvc does aggressive comdat folding.  Functions that are identical shaee an address.  It is ambiguous if this is legal under the standard, but it happens.

It checks for identical at the level of "can I use the same implementation at the machine code level and get the required result in the abstract machine".

This can also be disabled via `/OPT:NOICF`, but that can lead to huge bloat especially with template functions.

Instead, simply make functions have fundamentally different behaviour and state.

Comment: that is not true..even if I change the signature of all the functions used in dll they have the same entry point.

Comment: @zubair Do they still do nothing?  Then msvc can comdat fold.  Change all 3 to return `int`.  Have one return 1, the second 2, the third 3.

Comment: this is just an example I may put any random code inside the functions of this dll...but they should behave as expected

Comment: @Zubair - It is not  "just an example" as this code hits a specific feature of the MS compiler/linker. Functions with identical code are merged. This works fine for removing duplicate template instantiations, but has some side-effects.

Comment: DLLs aren't covered by the standard so IMO it can not be argued that the standard forbids this ; we're in extension-land

Comment: @m.m It happening in DLLs is a side effect of it happening everywhere.